# How to use Split() for a specific space?

Tags: vb.net

I want to split "float a, b, c;" and the output I want is for "float" to be separated to
"a, b, c;" but it still counts all other spaces.

The length of the string also counts the other spaces. Any suggestion on how can i split 
"float" from "a, b, c;"  so that my string will be divided in to two..

Comment: What do you mean by "The length of the string also counts the other spaces"? If you merely want to split on the first space and not the others, check out the version of `Split` that lets you specify the maximum number of splits.

Comment: i mean if i enter " have you eat?" the split length will 3 because it will be divided into "have", "you", "eat?". my aim is to separate "have" from "you eat?" i don't know what version of split should i use because i'm not too familiar with it..

Comment: My answer does just that.

Comment: If DonA answer doesnt answer you question then maybe you need to clarify more.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string using the space as the index for the substring method.

```
Dim theString As String = "float a: b: c:"
Dim firstSpace As Integer = theString.IndexOf(" ")
Dim firstWord = theString.Substring(0, firstSpace)
Dim rest = theString.Substring(firstSpace)
Debug.Write(String.Format("{0}|{1}", firstWord, rest))
```

Comment: it does split the "float" from "a: b: c:".. but if you get the number length of string it is no equal to 2, if you enter the String.length the number will be 14..

Comment: can you please check my codes.. it reads all other spaces so the length becomes big.. i can't use the .length because the length doesn't have an exact value..
http://i.stack.imgur.com/fViwt.png

Comment: I don't your making yourself clear. I have separated your string into 2 diff one based on the first space it encounters. I don't understand what you are saying about the length.

Comment: This is overkill. Just use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) of `String.Split`.

Answer (score 0):

if you know that the string is like "float a,b,c", just ignore the first 5 characters (s.substring(5) ), then split on ",", then trim the spaces.

```
Dim figures = (from f in s.substring(5).split(",") select f.trim(" ")).ToArray()
```

Comment: i cannot ignore the first string because when i split them the program will count automatically in how many did the string were divided ..